# Difference between save() and put()?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

What is the difference between Mymodel.save() and Mymodel.put() in appengine with python?
I know that save is used in django but does is work with appengine models too?

Comment: Since save() is undefined here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html  it's hard to figure out what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

save() is a (deprecated) alias for put(). They work exactly equivalently - in fact, they're the same function!